# Solver Recommendation : Discrete Variables and Quadratic Constraints

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint-programming, quadratic-programming, cp-sat

I would like some solver recommendations to solve a problem with boolean/integer variables, mostly **linear constraints but also some quadratic constraints**. I also have an **objective to minimize which is linear**.

I think this kind of problem is called mixed integer quadratically constrained program (**MIQCP**).

The quadratic constraints are sums of linear terms and **one quadratic term which is a constant multiplied by a squared variable**.

I would like to know if there is some MIP solvers that can handle this kind of problem (I think CPLEX and Gurobi can).

I would also like to know if a CP (Constraint programming) solver can handle this kind of constraint ? I looked at Google's or-tools CP-SAT solver documentation and it appears that there is a function AddMultiplicationEquality() that allows for variable products.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A key question is whether the quadratic constraints keep the continuous relaxation of the problem convex or not. Assuming the constant multiplying the squared variable is positive, a <= constraint would maintain convexity; >= or = would not.

Comment: Thanks ! From what you are telling me, this constraint would make the problem non convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means a complete list, but this is some of the best stuff for this mathematical structure:

**Open source:**

Couenne, SCIP

**Commercial and free:**

Octeract Engine (our own solver).

**Commercial and not free:**

Gurobi, Lindo Global, Baron, Antigone, LocalSolver.

You might be able to get a free version of Gurobi (and maybe some of the other non-free ones) if you are an academic.

If your problem is convex, you can also use Bonmin (open source), KNITRO (commercial), or MOSEK (commercial).

Comment: Mosek (https://mosek.com) for convex problems could be added to that list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! I will give a try to some of them. I will probably do this in Julia with JuMP since a wrapper exist for most of them.

Comment: You can add LocalSolver in the list of commercial and not free solvers. Somewhat strange, but LocalSolver is now a global optimization solver :-) https://www.localsolver.com